# Error during installation of smatch in ubuntu 14.10

Tags: dependencies

I tried to install smatch but I'm getting some errors:

I did:

```
$ git clone git://repo.or.cz/smatch.git
$ cd smatch
$ make
Makefile:107: Your system does not have libgtk2, disabling test-inspect
     LINK     sparse-llvm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ledit
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:211: recipe for target 'sparse-llvm' failed
make: *** [sparse-llvm] Error 1
```

So I tried to install:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgtk2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.27.3) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev (>= 2.21.0) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libatk1.0-dev (>= 1.29.2) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libcairo2-dev (>= 1.6.4-6.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any help?

Comment: Btw, I've modified my answer to provide you with the surest way of fixing your dependency problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter these two commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Try to fix the broken dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

And enter again `sudo apt-get -f install`.

This should solve your dependency problems and you can now install `libgtk2` again.